# Solving PDE for Diffusion Equation with Both Ideal and Excess Potential (Boundary Condition Issue)

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve this partial diffusion equation shown

$$\dfrac{\partial C_A}{\partial t}=D_A\left[\dfrac{\partial^2C_A}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac2r\dfrac{\partial C_A}{\partial r}+\dfrac1{K_BT}\dfrac1{r^2}\dfrac{\partial\left(r^2C_A\dfrac{\partial\mu_{\text{ext},A}}{\partial r}\right)}{\partial r}\right]$$

```
(*Clear all global variables*)ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Define a function for the spatial step size*)
d[rStar_] := 
3/10000 + 1/10000*(Tanh[25*(rStar - 0.2)] + Tanh[-25*(rStar + 0.2)])

(*Initialize variables for the simulation*)
xlist = {0};
xend = xlist[[Length[xlist]]];
coord = {{1}};
i = 1;

(*Generate a list of spatial coordinates based on the defined step \
size function*)
While[xend < 1, i = i + 1;
coord = Join[coord, {{i}}];
xend = xend + d[xend];
If[xend > 1, xend = 1;, xend = xend;];
xlist = Insert[xlist, xend, (Length[xlist] + 1)];]

(*Load the Finite Element Method package*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*Create a 1D mesh based on the generated spatial coordinates*)
xmesh = ToElementMesh[Map[{#} &, xlist]]
(*Set up physical and numerical parameters*)
 Dcoeff = 10^-29;
 Rmax = 100*10^-6;
 eps = 0.1;
 Cs = 1;
kB = 1.38*10^-23;
T = 25 + 273;
tmax = 1*10^21;
timeC = 1
A = Dcoeff*tmax/(Rmax^2)
x = -1;
B1 = 10000;
D1 = 0.1;

(*Define a function for the chemical potential*)
Mui[rStar_] = (x*kB*T)/2*(1 - Tanh[B1 (rStar - D1)]);

(*Define a function for the source term in the differential equation*)
df[rStar_, tStar_] := Csol[rStar, tStar]*rStar^2*D[Mui[rStar], rStar];

(*Solve the 1D diffusion-reaction equation using the Finite Element \
Method*)
 sol = NDSolve[{D[Csol[rStar, tStar], tStar] == 
  A*(D[Csol[rStar, tStar], rStar, rStar] + (2/rStar)*
      D[Csol[rStar, tStar], rStar] + 
     1/(kB*T)/rStar^2*D[df[rStar, tStar], rStar]) + 
  NeumannValue[0, rStar == 0], Csol[rStar, 0] == 1, 
  DirichletCondition[Csol[rStar, tStar] == 0.2, rStar == 1]}, 
  Csol, {rStar, 0, 1}, {tStar, 0, timeC}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
   "MeshOptions" -> {"IncludePoints" -> xmesh["Coordinates"]}}}];

 (*Define a function to extract concentration from the solution*)
 concentration[rStar_, tStar_] := Csol[rStar, tStar] /. sol[[1]];

 (*Plot concentration against rStar for different time steps*)
 Grid[Partition[
 Table[Plot[Evaluate[concentration[rStar, tStar]], {rStar, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 4}, FrameLabel -> {"r", "Concentration"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
 "t = " <> ToString[tStar] <> " (Non-Dimensionalize)"], {tStar, 0,
 timeC, timeC*0.1}], 5], Spacings -> {10, 2}]

(*Plot concentration against r for the final time step*)
Plot[Evaluate[concentration[rStar, timeC]], {rStar, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {0, 4}, FrameLabel -> {"r", "Concentration"}, 
PlotLabel -> "t = " <> ToString[timeC] <> " (Non-Dimensionalize)"]
```

It evaluates fine, however when plotting seen in the image below, it does not follow the dirichlet condition that states that rStar= 1 , the concentration = 0.2.
[image]

I am aware of the solution provided for a different scenario ie:

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines",    "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}
```

This method does solve the issue of the BC, however the graphs produce do not capture the behavior of the last term in the diffusion equation which results in a partition effect shown in the image above. I do hope a solution can be provided for this issue.

[image]

Comment: …You should combine both option i.e. `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"IncludePoints" -> xmesh["Coordinates"]}}}`